# Google Scheduled Cloud Function not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-functions

Not really sure what the issue is or really how to deploy it, my code is as follows:

```
exports.autoLockWeek = functions.pubsub.schedule('50 20 * * FRI')
.timeZone('America/New_York')
.onRun((context) => {
    
    sceduleLockRef.child("AutoLockWeek").once('value').then(function(snap) {

        gamesRef.orderByChild("WeekId").equalTo(parseInt(snap.val())).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

            snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
            
                gamesRef.child(child.key).update({

                    isPlayed: true
                
                });
                
            });

        });

    });

    return null;

});
```

I am unsure how do i deploy this now?!

I was able to deploy it, as I can see it in my cloud functions list but when the time 'hit' the function did not trigger like i was expecting!?

Comment: It's challenging to help. You don't include details of the commands you used to deploy the function nor what you observed (logs?) that leads to your conclusion that it didn't work. The function itself uses a possibly undefined variable `sceduleRef` (did you mean to call it `scheduleRef`?). Where is its value defined? Have you tried adding logging statements to the function so that you may track its state? The promises don't have `catch` blocks which would be helpful for catching errors too.

Comment: @DazWilkin the function itself works as desired, if i use the `Test the Function` button in the Test tab. My question is that the schedule `.schedule('50 20 * * FRI')` is not being triggered. How do i do that portion if anyone knows?!

Comment: Interesting. OK. Have you fulfilled the [requirements](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#before_you_begin)? Blaze plan, Pub/Sub and Scheduler enabled? I don't use Firebase and haven't tried this functionality. Assuming that it uses Cloud Scheduler, have you checked Jobs in the Console or its logs (`cloudscheduler.googleapis.com/executions`)?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions are short-lived and exit when they've finished their execution or after a set timeout (max 9 minutes for 1st gen, 60 minutes for 2nd gen). So you can't set a schedule within your function as it wont be running to be able to execute it.

You need to set the schedule ***outside*** of your function which can trigger the function to execute. You can [do this using Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating). This can manage the cron schedule as a job and trigger the function by making a HTTP request to the URL.

Comment: so i was following along the following instructions : `https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions` along with the video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4wgrgb24o0&t=613s`. It should allow me to do both on deployment and not required to do separate at least from what i can tell. Doing it separate works, and i needed to use a HTTP trigger which now has an extra level of being exposed. It would have been nicer if it just worked as the links showed is all.